# I want both English & Marathi Language on one screen. How is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can anybody help me out in this situation. I want to use one entry in Marathi language and one entry in English Language through textbox in ASP. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

One common way to localize applications into different languages is to store the text for each language in its own resource file (e.g. a DLL). The code contains a key to look up the correct piece of text in the resource file for the language that the user is working in.

I haven't seen an application that uses two languages at the same time, but the same principle would apply: the code would look up the text once in the English resource file, and a second time in the Marathi resource file.

Free-form text in a textbox poses additional problems. This would be much more like translation software, but I'm not sure if this is the problem that you want to solve.